# how to start remote weblogic server using ant script?

Tags: ant, weblogic12c

I want to start the remote weblogic server using ant script.
I have created ant script that stop and start the weblogic server,for local weblogic server stop and start work nicely but when i tried to use same ant script for remote weblogic server,it work for stop but for start it running,not throwing any error.

```
<project name="Svn" default="startserver">
<property name="wldeploy.source" value="napf-main/napf-build/release/target/Release/dist/nfapp.ear" />
<property name="basedir" location="C:/Jenkinserver/workspace/NAPF_PRO/NAPF_SERVER_SOURCE"/> 
<property name="ant.home" location="D:/tools/apache-ant-1.10.1"/> 
<property name="wls.home" value="C:/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver"/> 

<property name="wldeploy.admin.protocol" value="t3"/> 
<property name="wldeploy.admin.host" value="10.254.6.206"/> 
<property name="wldeploy.admin.port" value="7001"/> 
<property name="wldeploy.user" value="weblogic" />
<property name="wldeploy.password" value="weblogic12.2.1" />
<property name="admin.server.name" value="AdminServer" />
<property name="wl.domain.name" value="NAPF_domain" />

<property name="wldeploy.verbose" value="true"/> 
<property name="wldeploy.debug" value="false"/> 
<property name="wldeploy.targets" value="AdminServer"/> 
<property name="wldeploy.nonExclLock" value="true"/> 
<property name="wldeploy.upload" value="true"/>
<property name="wldeploy.remote" value="true"/>

    <target name="deploy">  
    <echo message="basedir: ${basedir}"/>  
    <echo message="ant.home: ${ant.home}"/>  
    <echo message="wls.home: ${wls.home}"/>  
    <property name="wldeploy.admin.url"  
              value="${wldeploy.admin.protocol}://${wldeploy.admin.host}:${wldeploy.admin.port}/"/>  
    <property name="wldeploy.classpath" value="${wls.home}/modules/features/wlst.wls.classpath.jar"/>  
    <!-- windows -->  
    <exec dir="${basedir}" executable="cmd" osfamily="windows">  
        <env key="CLASSPATH" value="${wldeploy.classpath}"/>  
        <env key="ANT_HOME" value="${ant.home}"/>  
        <arg value="/c"/>  
        <arg value="${ant.home}/bin/ant"/>  
        <arg value="-Dwldeploy.verbose=${wldeploy.verbose}"/>  
        <arg value="-Dwldeploy.debug=${wldeploy.debug}"/>  
        <arg value="-Dwldeploy.nonExclLock=${wldeploy.nonExclLock}"/> 
        <arg value="-Dwldeploy.upload=${wldeploy.upload}"/>  
       <!--  <arg value="-Dwldeploy.appName=${wldeploy.appName}"/>  -->
        <arg value="-Dwldeploy.source=${wldeploy.source}"/>  
       <!-- <arg value="-Dwldeploy.plan=${wldeploy.plan}"/>  -->
        <arg value="-Dwldeploy.user=${wldeploy.user}"/>  
        <arg value="-Dwldeploy.password=${wldeploy.password}"/>  
        <arg value="-Dwldeploy.admin.url=${wldeploy.admin.url}"/>  
        <arg value="-Dwldeploy.targets=${wldeploy.targets}"/>  
        <arg value="-Dwldeploy.admin.host=${wldeploy.admin.host}"/>
        <arg value="-Dwldeploy.admin.port=${wldeploy.admin.port}"/>
        <!-- target -->
        <arg value="stop-server"/>  
        <arg value="start-server"/>  
        <!--<arg value="wldeploy"/> --> 
    </exec>  
</target>  

 <target name="stop-server" description="stop to a WebLogic domain">  
   <taskdef name="wlserver" classname="weblogic.ant.taskdefs.management.WLServer"/>
    <wlserver  adminserverurl="${wldeploy.admin.url}" username="${wldeploy.user}" password="${wldeploy.password}" servername="${admin.server.name}" action="shutdown" noexit="true" host="${wldeploy.admin.host}" port="${wldeploy.admin.port}"/>
    <sleep seconds="2" />
</target>

 <target name="start-server">
    <wlserver dir="C:/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/user_projects/domains/NAPF_domain"  host="${wldeploy.admin.host}" port="${wldeploy.admin.port}" domainname="${wl.domain.name}" servername="${admin.server.name}" action="start" username="${wldeploy.user}" password="${wldeploy.password}"  weblogichome="${wls.home}" verbose="true" noexit="true" protocol="${wldeploy.admin.protocol}">
    </wlserver>
</target>

<target name="wldeploy" description="Deploy to a WebLogic domain">  
    <taskdef name="wldeploy" classname="weblogic.ant.taskdefs.management.WLDeploy"/>  
          <wldeploy action="deploy" verbose="${wldeploy.verbose}" debug="${wldeploy.debug}"  
          source="${wldeploy.source}" user="${wldeploy.user}" password="${wldeploy.password}"  
          adminurl="${wldeploy.admin.url}" targets="${wldeploy.targets}" usenonexclusivelock="${wldeploy.nonExclLock}" upload="${wldeploy.upload}" remote="${wldeploy.remote}"/>
</target>
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Why are you executing Ant from Ant, and passing the properties from the same script?

Comment: I am getting error while running wldeploy ant script- "[wldeploy] C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\PROJ\workspace\build.xml:574: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "D:\jdk1.7\jre\bin\java.exe": CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long", for resolve the issue i have found post https://community.oracle.com/thread/4017829 that suggest the way that resolve the error=206.

Comment: How do you remote to that machine? Ssh, telnet?

Comment: I am using RDS to access that machine.

Comment: Using ant script, able to shutdown server mean access that machine is not an issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have started remote weblogic server using WLST script using node manager.
Few point to be consider while starting remote weblogic server.

1.Local weblogic server need to be running while executing wlst start command.

2.Node manager of remote weblogic server need to be on running mode.

3.domains.properties contains setting for remote weblogic server and node.

**For More details refer :**

**http://100bytes.com/tutorials/weblogic/weblogic-server-start-stop-operations**
**http://weblogic-tips.com/2012/02/17/starting-the-administration-server-using-node-manager-and-wlst-2/**

**build.xml**

```
<project name="ws">
<property name="oracle.home" value="C:/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home" />
<property name="wl.home" value="C:/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver" />

<path id="wl.classpath">
<fileset dir="${wl.home}/server/lib">
<include name="*.jar"/>
</fileset>
</path>

<taskdef name="wlst" classpathref="wl.classpath" classname="weblogic.ant.taskdefs.management.WLSTTask" />

<target name="Shutdown-server" >
<echo message="WebLogic Home is : ${wl.home}" />
    <wlst debug="true" executescriptbeforefile="false" filename="wlstscript/StopAdminServer.py" failonerror="false"  classpathref="wl.classpath"> 
    </wlst>
</target>

<target name="Start-server" >
<echo message="WebLogic Home is : ${wl.home}" />
    <wlst debug="true" executescriptbeforefile="true" failonerror="false" filename="wlstscript/StartAdminServer.py"  classpathref="wl.classpath"> 
    </wlst>
</target>
</project>
```

**domains.properties**

```
node.username=weblogic
node.password=weblogic123
node.host=10.254.5.186
node.port=5556
node.type=plain
server.name=AdminServer
server.url=t3://10.254.5.186:7001
server.user=weblogic
server.password=weblogic12.2.1
domain.name=NAPF_domain
domain.dir=C:/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/user_projects/domains/NAPF_domain
```

**StopAdminServer.py**

```
#############################################################################
#
# This Script is used to stop the admin server using WLST script.
#
#############################################################################
from java.io import FileInputStream
import java.lang
import os
import string

propInputStream = FileInputStream("wlstscript/domains.properties")
configProps = Properties()
configProps.load(propInputStream)

Username = configProps.get("server.user")
Password = configProps.get("server.password")
serverUrl = configProps.get("server.url")
serverName= configProps.get("server.name")

connect(Username,Password,serverUrl)
print ''
print '============================================='
print 'Connected to Admin Server Successfully...!!!'
print '============================================='
print ''
shutdown(serverName,'Server','false',1000, block='false') 
print ''
print '============================================='
print ' ShutDown Admin Server Successfully...!!!'
print '============================================='
print ''
```

**StartAdminServer.py**

```
#############################################################################
#
# This Script is used to start the admin server using node manager.
#
#############################################################################
from java.io import FileInputStream
import java.lang
import os
import string

propInputStream = FileInputStream("wlstscript/domains.properties")
configProps = Properties()
configProps.load(propInputStream)

Username = configProps.get("node.username")
Password = configProps.get("node.password")
Host = configProps.get("node.host")
nmPort = configProps.get("node.port")
domainName = configProps.get("domain.name")
domainDir = configProps.get("domain.dir")
nmType = configProps.get("node.type")


nmConnect(Username,Password,Host,nmPort,domainName,domainDir,nmType)
print ''
print '============================================='
print 'Connected to NODE MANAGER Successfully...!!!'
print '============================================='
print ''
serverName = configProps.get("server.name")
print '###### serverName = ', serverName

nmStart(serverName)
serverName = configProps.get("server.name")
print ''
print '============================================='
print '===> Successfully started ', serverName, '  <==='
print '============================================='
print ''
nmDisconnect()
```